# Why doesn't to_proc work inside Ruby refinements?

Tags: ruby, proc, refinements

It seems that `to_proc` doesn't work on methods defined in refinements:

```
module ArrayExtensions
  refine Array do
    def sum
      reduce(0, :+)
    end
  end
end

using ArrayExtensions

puts [[1, 2, 3]].map { |array| array.sum } # => 6
puts [[1, 2, 3]].map(&:sum) # => array.rb:13:in `map': undefined method `sum' for [1, 2, 3]:Array (NoMethodError)
puts [1, 2, 3].method(:sum).to_proc.call # => array.rb:14:in `method': undefined method `sum' for class `Array' (NameError)
```

Is this the intended behavior? Is there a workaround?

Comment: It's the other way around. Methods defined in refinements do not work in procs created by `Symbol#to_proc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NB** The answer below is correct for legacy rubies. In Ruby 2.5+ `map(&:sum)` works *as expected*.

---

[Scoping of refinements](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html#label-Scope) is restricted to *current context*. Since refinements are intended to be *not global*, as an opposite to *monkey patches*, any try to call the refined method from outside is prevented. In the code below:

```
puts [[1, 2, 3]].map { |array| array.sum } # => 6
```

the scope is fine, we are inside the same scope where this refinement was defined. But here:

```
puts [[1, 2, 3]].map(&:sum)
```

the scope is transferred to the context of `Symbol` class (!). As stated in the documentation:

> When control is transferred outside the scope the refinement is deactivated.

The analogy here would be a private method. Though, while it is exactly as stated in docs, I am unsure whether this behaviour is intended. I believe, an interpreter should take care about such cases. But this question is better to address Matz :)

*P.S.* Good question!

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is intended. The scope for a refinement is either the module block or the file where `using` was called. In your `(&:sum)`, you are not (explicitly) calling the method `sum`; you only have a symbol `:sum` there. Calling is done somewhere in the Ruby C-implementation when `Symbol#to_proc` is used. That environment is where your refinement is not effective.

A workaround is to explicitly call the method within that file.