# Ruby: Why does this way of using map throw an error?

Tags: ruby

I tried to shorten

`values.map { |value| value.gsub!("\n", ' ') }`

with

`values.map(&:gsub!("\n", ' '))`

but it gives me an:

```
SyntaxError:
...csv_creator.rb:40: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'
     values.map(&:gsub!("\n", ' '))
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&:foo` may erroneously be seen as `&:` plus `foo` (terms like "[pretzel colon](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22pretzel+colon%22)" reinforce this mistaken view). But no method `foo` is being called here. `&:foo` is actually `&` plus `:foo`, the latter being a plain symbol.

When calling a method, `&object` (without `:`) invokes `object.to_proc` (which is supposed to return a [`Proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Proc.html)) and passes the returned proc as a *block argument* to the method.

`object` often happens to be a symbol and [`Symbol#to_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc)'s implementation would look somehow like this in Ruby: (it's actually written in C)

```
class Symbol
  def to_proc
    proc { |object, *args| object.public_send(self, *args) }
  end
end
```

So this:

```
method(&:symbol)
```

effectively becomes this:

```
method { |object, *args| object.public_send(:symbol, *args) }
```

or, if `method` doesn't yield multiple values (like `map`), it's simply:

```
method { |object| object.public_send(:symbol) }
```

Obviously, you can't pass additional arguments via a symbol.

But ... `object` doesn't have to be a symbol. You could use another class with a custom `to_proc` implementation. Let's abuse `Array` for demonstration purposes:

```
class Array
  def to_proc
    method, *args = self
    proc { |obj| obj.public_send(method, *args) }
  end
end
```

This hack would allow you to write:

```
["foo\nbar", "baz\nqux"].map(&[:gsub, "\n", '-'])
#=> ["foo-bar", "baz-qux"]
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`&:method` notation is using `#to_proc` method, which is capable of converting symbol to `Proc` object. It can't be used as a shortcut if you need to provide additional arguments to called method.

Longer explanation about `#to_proc` can be found in separate answer: [What does to_proc method mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881125/what-does-to-proc-method-mean)

Answer (score 1):

## Alternatives

#### String#methods

Just to show what could be done : you could define `String` methods without arguments.

```
class String
  def replace_newlines!(replace = ' ')
    gsub!("\n", replace)
  end

  def replace_newlines(replace = ' ')
    gsub("\n", replace)
  end
end

p new_values = values.map(&:replace_newlines)
#=> ["1 2", "a b"]

p values.each(&:replace_newlines!)
#=> ["1 2", "a b"]
```

Sadly, [refinements](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) [wouldn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35333222/why-doesnt-to-proc-work-inside-ruby-refinements) with `to_proc`.

#### Proc

Another possibility would be to define a new `Proc`, without monkey-patching `String` :

```
my_gsub = proc { |string| string.gsub("\n", ' ') }
p new_values = values.map(&my_gsub)
#=> ["1 2", "a b"]
```

## each/map/gsub/gsub!

Note that `map` doesn't make much sense when used with `!` methods. You should either :

- use `map` with `gsub`
- or use `each` with `gsub!`

Comment: Good idea..but I don't think my boss would like me to mess around with the String class..

Comment: Fair enough, let's say it's just to show what could be done. The advice on `map` and `gsub!` still stands, though.

Comment: +1 for that..unfortunately your answer doesn't answer my main question (why it wouldn't work), so I can't accept it as the best answer, even though it has more additional info.

Comment: Sure, no problem. @samuil had a valid answer before I posted mine. I just wanted to add a few points that wouldn't fit in a comment.

Comment: Very good points, I have to say. Neither did I know or think about `map` not making sense with !-methods nor did I know about refinements. Lessons learned!

Comment: Sorry to come back a bit delayed, but WHY is map not making sense with gsub!? Ahwell, I will open a new question..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41854955/ruby-is-it-true-that-map-generally-doesnt-make-sense-with-bang-methods