# Ruby: Is it true that #map generally doesn't make sense with bang methods?

Tags: ruby

This question was inspired by this one:
[Ruby: Why does this way of using map throw an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41853364/ruby-why-does-this-way-of-using-map-throw-an-error/41853662?noredirect=1#comment70891676_41853662)

Someone pointed out the following:

**map doesn't make much sense when used with ! methods.**

You should either:

- use map with gsub
- or use each with gsub!

Can someone explain why that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Base object

Here's an array with strings as element :

```
words = ['hello', 'world']
```

## New array

If you want a new array with modified strings, you can use `map` with `gsub` :

```
new_words = words.map{|word| word.gsub('o','#') }

p new_words
#=> ["hell#", "w#rld"]
p words
#=> ["hello", "world"]
p new_words == words
#=> false
```

The original strings and the original array aren't modified.

## Strings modified in place

If you want to modify the strings in place, you can use :

```
words.each{|word| word.gsub!('o','#') }
p words
#=> ["hell#", "w#rld"]
```

## map and gsub!

```
new_words = words.map{|word| word.gsub!('o','#') }
p words
#=> ["hell#", "w#rld"]
p new_words
#=> ["hell#", "w#rld"]
p words == new_words
#=> true
p new_words.object_id
#=> 12704900
p words.object_id
#=> 12704920
```

Here, a new array is created, but the elements are the exact same ones!

It doesn't bring anything more than the previous examples. It creates a new Array for nothing. It also might confuse people reading your code by sending opposite signals :

- `gsub!` will indicate that you want to modifiy existing objects
- `map` will indicate that you don't want to modify existing objects.

Answer (score 1):

Map is for building a new array without mutating the original. Each is for performing some action on each element of an array. Doing both at once is surprising.

```
>> arr = ["foo bar", "baz", "quux"]
=> ["foo bar", "baz", "quux"]
>> arr.map{|x| x.gsub!(' ', '-')}
=> ["foo-bar", nil, nil]
>> arr
=> ["foo-bar", "baz", "quux"]
```

Since !-methods generally have side effects (and only incidentally might return a value), `each` should be preferred to `map` when invoking a !-method.

An exception might be when you have a list of actions to perform. The method to perform the action might sensibly be named with a `!`, but you wish to collect the results in order to report which ones succeeded or failed.